# To count number of matches in a mega string quickly

Tags: shell-script, sed, find

I have big text-data without spaces and without other rows in one line.
In reality, the streams are 0.2 Gb/s, similar situation [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82418/16920), but in this task, counting occurrences which is more challenging computationally than just counting empty lines. 
The match is

```
585e0000fe5a1eda480000000d00030007000000cd010000
```

Example data subset is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/khszx6w21d7423a/30.6.2015_data.txt?dl=0) called *30.6.2015_data.txt* and its full binary data [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ywb07kcd7s7a3z9/0002.raw?dl=0) called *0002.raw*. 
The match occurs 1 time in *30.6.2015_data.txt* but 10 times in the full data *0002.raw* in one line. 
I prepared the txt data by `xxd -ps 0002.raw > /tmp/1 && fold -w2 /tmp/1 > /tmp/2 && gsed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' /tmp/2 > /tmp/3`. 
The faster implementation, the better. 
To prepare the mega string in column, you can use this `xxd -ps 0002.raw > /tmp/1 && fold -w2 /tmp/1 > /tmp/2`. 
My current rate is 0.0012 s per match i.e. 0.012 s per ten matches in the full data file, which is slow.

Grep does this in rows so not possible in counting. 
In Vim, `%s/veryLongThing//gn` is insufficient for the task. 
The command `wc` is giving only character, byte and lines so not correct tool but probably by combining it to something else. 
Possibly GNU Find and Sed combination but all implementations seems to be too complicated.

### Outputs of Mikeserv's answer

```
$ cat 1.7.2015.sh 
time \
    ( export ggrep="$(printf '^ \376Z\36\332H \r \3 \a \315\1')" \
             gtr='\1\3\a\r\36HZ^\315\332\376'
             LC_ALL=C
      gtr -cs "$gtr" ' [\n*]' |
      gcut -sd\  -f1-6       |
      ggrep -xFc "$ggrep"
    ) <0002.raw

$ sh 1.7.2015.sh 
1

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.006s
sys 0m0.007s

-----------

$ cat 1.7.2015.sh 
time \
    (  set      x58 x5e x20 x20 xfe x5a x1e xda \
                x48 x20 x20 x20 x0d x20 x03 x20 \
                x07 x20 x20 x20 xcd x01 x20 x20
        export  ggrep="$(shift;IFS=\\;printf "\\$*")"    \
                gtr='\0\1\3\a\r\36HXZ^\315\332\376'      \
                LC_ALL=C i=0
        while [ "$((i+=1))" -lt 1000 ]
        do    gcat 0002.raw; done            |
        gtr -cd "$gtr" |gtr 'X\0' '\n '      |
        gcut -c-23    |ggrep -xFc "$ggrep"
    ) 

$ sh 1.7.2015.sh 
9990

real    0m4.371s
user    0m1.548s
sys 0m2.167s
```

where all tools are GNU coreutils and they have all options you provide in the code. They may however differ with GNU devtools. 
Mikeserv runs his code 990 times and there are 10 events so total 9990 events is correct.

How can you count the number of matches in a megastring efficiently?

Comment: But that's the hex again. Can you get the stream in binary? If you just pass the binary stream through `od -An -tx1` you'll get the stream at 16 hexadecimally-econded bytes per line. My own preference is for `od -An -tu1`, though, which does it all in simple unsigned ints ranged 0 -255. *And* I'm showing `-An` there to drop the offset list, but you might keep it and first filter by the offsets you want, *then* filter for the strings you want. Anyway, to handle the long string thing, first break the stream by line, *then* find it. `...|fold -w2`

Comment: Anyway, where's the data? Because I'd like to try [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212774/52934) on it.

Comment: That sounds like it would take me a long time to download... D you have representative sample?

Comment: oh, nevermind. It's only 230k.

Comment: You're not doing ADC, you're doing CDA, I guess... Or maybe that's affected by endianness? Anyway, have you looked at `strings -td -3 <0002.raw`? It looks like there is a definite field separator on *CDA* every 6k or so... Is that relevant?

Comment: it's not a switch. The `-t` is the switch - it just lets you choose what format to print the byte offset with. `strings -td -3` means print each non-white-space *`string`* of at least `-3` bytes in length preceded by its decimal byte-offset and followed by a newline.

Comment: How about `LC_ALL=C grep -ao CDA | wc -l`?

Comment: @Masi - the string you're looking for - does it only occur the one time in 0002.raw? I get it in .010sec w/ `time (export LC_ALL=C; tr 'X\0 \n' '\n X\0' </tmp/0002.raw | cut -c-23 | grep -xFc "$(printf '^  \376Z\36\332H   \r \3 \a   \315\1  ')")`, but i only get one result. Are you definitely looking to count that one string's occurrence? I'm still not totally clear on what is wanted here. The command above should rule out any possibility of finding anything but the data you want.

Comment: @Masi - 0 matches? No - i got one match.

Comment: You have to use the `grep -xFc "$(printf '^...)"` thing - `printf` translates the escapes to bytes. Oh and there are supposed to be two spaces at the end. You might try `grep -xFc "$(printf %b "$(echo 585e0000fe5a1eda480000000d00030007000000cd010000 | sed 's/../\\x&/g')")"`

Comment: Wait... So it did work or it didn't? Oh... That last one I said won't work for sure - it hasn't been sanitized. It won't match because `tr`'s job is to make sure that every time that string occurs it does on a line by itself - the X is first character and we translate those to newlines and there are 24 bytes - one now a newline - and `cut` won't let any line through more than 23 bytes.

Comment: @Masi - it was wrong. I posted an answer about it.

Comment: @Masi - of cpurse you get 0 results. you name the variable `$gtr` and then call it like `gtr "$tr"`. You need tonuse consistent names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GNU implementation of `grep` (also found in most modern BSDs though the latest versions are a complete (mostly compatible) rewrite) supports a `-o` option to output *all* the matched portions.

```
LC_ALL=C grep -ao CDA | wc -l
```

would then count all the occurrences.

```
LC_ALL=C grep -abo CDA
```

to locate them with their byte offset.

`LC_ALL=C` makes sure `grep` doesn't try and do some expensive UTF-8 parsing (though here, with a fixed ASCII string search, `grep` should be able to optimise away the UTF-8 parsing by itself). `-a` is another GNUism to tell `grep` to consider binary files.

Comment: Is the *mostly compatible* difference about the GNU implementation's dependence on GNU's C libs' *perlesque* regexp? And the CDA thing - is that because of my comment before, or is it also in *585e0000fe5a1eda480000000d00030007000000cd010000*? ...because I didn't try to parse that... I *think* the CDA thing is relevant, but I'm not certain...

Comment: I am evaluating the performance of these commands. They at least 2x faster than my current command. I get much fluctuation in timing their performance. I am studying how to do timing better here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/213230/16920

Comment: You can probably speed things up a little with a hand-crafted [Boyer-Moore](http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/tunedbm.html) (window sliding can be optimized for infinite streams).  But as far as standard tools are concerned, the above is about as fast as it gets.

Comment: @mikeserv, they diverged slightly after they were rewritten from scratch (different options and option handling (for instance wrt -r IIRC). BSDs `grep` are now backward compatible to the old version of GNU grep they were originally based on, but no longer to recent versions of GNU grep or even between each other (IIRC Apple's one diverged from FreeBSD for instance).

Comment: @Masi, timing will be affected by the system's caching. If the data is not in cache, then the bottleneck will be disk I/O, not grep.

Comment: But this doesn't find the string asked for...? It's why I asked you before why you were looking for CDA at all?

Answer (score 1):

So I took your hex string and printed it out to bytes, but I swapped the NULs for <spaces> *(mostly because I can't figure on how to get a NUL in a `grep` pattern)*:

```
time \
    (  set      x58 x5e x20 x20 xfe x5a x1e xda \
                x48 x20 x20 x20 x0d x20 x03 x20 \
                x07 x20 x20 x20 xcd x01 x20 x20
        export  grep="$(shift;IFS=\\;printf "\\$*")"    \
                tr='\0\1\3\a\r\36HXZ^\315\332\376'      \
                LC_ALL=C i=0
        while [ "$((i+=1))" -lt 1000 ]
        do    cat 0002.raw; done     |
        tr -cd "$tr" |tr 'X\0' '\n ' |
        cut -c-23    |grep -xFc "$grep"
    )
```

The `tr` variable there is made up of octal escapes/ASCII chars for the byte values of your hex string because I wanted `tr` to `-d`elete its complement. I then made sure that the longest line `grep` could attempt to match against would be `-c-23` bytes with `cut`, and that the string would always head a line by `tr`anslating X chars to `\n`ewlines while also swapping the NULs for <spaces>.

I'm `cat`ing the raw binary at the pipeline 999 times here. Because there are 10 matches in the file, the results are:

```
9990
1.06s user 0.94s system 65% cpu 3.054 total
```

Now I also tested...

```sh
time \
    (  set      x58 x5e x20 x20 xfe x5a x1e xda \
                x48 x20 x20 x20 x0d x20 x03 x20 \
                x07 x20 x20 x20 xcd x01 x20 x20
        export  LC_ALL=C i=0 grep="$(IFS=\\;printf "\\$*")"
        while [ "$((i+=1))" -lt 1000 ]
        do    cat 0002.raw;  done    |
        tr '\0 ' ' \0'   |
        grep -aFo "$grep"| wc -l
    )
```

I use `wc -l` there but in my tests it didn't seem to make any difference execution time-wise to use `-caFo` and drop `wc` altogether. The counts were the same either way, anyway. The results for this:

```
9990
1.56s user 1.46s system 82% cpu 3.648 total
```

Now these two sets of commands are not equivalent. While it does seem to complete a little faster by squeezing out unwanted bytes w/ `tr` first, one thing that means is while you can get the count, you cannot get the offsets as you might by adding the `-b` switch to `grep` in the second example...

```sh
time \
   (    set     x58 x5e x20 x20 xfe x5a x1e xda \
                x48 x20 x20 x20 x0d x20 x03 x20 \
                x07 x20 x20 x20 xcd x01 x20 x20
        export  LC_ALL=C i=0 grep="$(IFS=\\;printf "\\$*")"
        while [ "$((i+=1))" -lt 1000 ]
        do    cat 0002.raw;  done    |
        tr '\0 ' ' \0'     |
        grep -baFo "$grep" | sed -n l
   )
```

---

```
...

241133568:X^  \376Z\036\332H   \r \003 \a   \315\001  $
241157720:X^  \376Z\036\332H   \r \003 \a   \315\001  $
241181872:X^  \376Z\036\332H   \r \003 \a   \315\001  $
241206024:X^  \376Z\036\332H   \r \003 \a   \315\001  $
241230176:X^  \376Z\036\332H   \r \003 \a   \315\001  $
241254328:X^  \376Z\036\332H   \r \003 \a   \315\001  $

1.59s user 1.41s system 85% cpu 3.496 total
```

And so which you choose, I guess, will depend on what you want. For just a count, probably the `tr -cd` will be better - it reliably completed a half second quicker than the other every time - but it is not as versatile, and so maybe, if your `grep` will support it, `grep -baFo` could be what you need instead.

Comment: @Masi - All of the tools I used were standard, as far as I know - I didn't take advantage of any nonstandard extensions. They should all work w/ a POSIX toolset. I posted a list of offsets where the string can be found.

Comment: _I swapped the NULs for \<spaces> (mostly because I can't figure on how to get a NUL in a `grep` pattern)_ - The shell can't handle NUL, but with GNU `grep` you can still pass the full binary pattern in a file: `LC_ALL=C fgrep -abof needle 0002.raw | tr -cd '\n[:print:]'`.  This doesn't work with BSD `grep` though.

Comment: @lcd047 - that's pretty cool, but does doing that make it faster - like does it run as quickly as the `tr`?

Comment: It makes your job easier.  You can edit the pattern in hex (say in `xxd -g1` format), then you decode it to a binary file and feed it to `grep`.  I don't think it changes the speed of matching in any way.

Comment: @Masi - i pipe the 0002.raw file at the pipeline 999 times, and because there are 10 matches in that file, the result is 9990.

Comment: @lcd047 - you can feed `grep` its pattern file over a pipe, if it is otherwise searching a named file, and so, if what you say is true, probably: `printf \\0\\1string\\1\\0' | grep -f- file` would work as well, yeah?

Comment: It should also work, yes.  But my point is `echo '00000000: 00 01 73 74 72 69 6e 67 01 00' | xxd -r` is easier to handle / edit for arbitrary binary data than `printf \\0\\1string\\1\\0`.